# Where is hostname value being sourced

Tags: shell, hostname, fish

I have a prompt on this mac mini that looks like the output below. I can seem to find where the `priscilla-cs-iphone` value is coming from.

```sh
mando@priscilla-cs-iphone ~> cat .config/fish/fish_variables | grep hostname
mando@priscilla-cs-iphone ~ [0|1]> cat .config/fish/fish_variables | grep home
mando@priscilla-cs-iphone ~ [0|1]> cat .config/fish/fish_variables | grep priscilla
mando@priscilla-cs-iphone ~ [0|1]> cat .config/fish/fish_variables | grep "priscilla"
mando@priscilla-cs-iphone ~ [0|1]> cat ~/.config/fish/fishd.(ifconfig en0 | awk '/ether/{print $2}' | tr -d ':')
cat: /Users/mando/.config/fish/fishd.1498773cea14: No such file or directory
```

System configuration...

```sh
mando@priscilla-cs-iphone ~ [1]> defaults read /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server
{
    DOSCodePage = 437;
    LocalKerberosRealm = "LKDC:SHA1.30D481C6036FC8F8B589EFF8E37B513D08753210";
    NetBIOSName = mandalarian;
    ServerDescription = mandalarian;
}
mando@priscilla-cs-iphone ~>
```

My `etc/hosts` file reads:

```sh
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Im on a mac mini:

```sh
> sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.2.3
BuildVersion:   20D91
```

I understand that I can reset it but I would like to know where the value is coming and how it might have been set to that. This is fresh BigSur install and I have never connected to an iphone that I am aware of in the last 24 hours.

Comment: Generally, on MacOS, your hostname (if not otherwise overridden) is set by the DHCP server of whatever network you're attached to. I'd argue that this question is more on-topic at [apple.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/); it's not meaningfully specific to software development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fish calls your operating system's `gethostname(3)` function.

Where that gets the value depends on the system. Where macOS gets it, I have absolutely no clue.

Comment: One thing I'm seeing is that $HOSTNAME and $hostname are different on my system. $HOSTNAME is what I want and what's configured in System Settings (user sharing). $hostname is just generic `MacBook-Pro`.

Comment: Fish sets $hostname by calling the operating system's `gethostname`. If that returns "MacBook-Pro", then your hostname isn't set in a way that gethostname sees. It does not set $HOSTNAME, so that is set elsewhere.